# How to keep tests running after Exception occured?

Tags: android, testing, robotium

Let's says I have 10 test cases and `Exception` happens on second of them. After it occur the rest of tests aren't going to start. How to keep running tests after `Exception` is happened?

Comment: When a test throws an exception it does try to run the other tests so i am not sure how you are running into this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

**Add other test-cases in catch block.**
Suppose exception will ocure in second testcase then you can add remaining testcases in that catch block.
Some time we need to use some functionality after getting Exception or after cached exception.
You can use Catch block for this.

```
try{  
 testcase1  
 testcase2  
 .  
 .  
 .  
 .  
 testcase10  
}    
catch(Exception e)  
{  
   if(testcase1.isExecute()||blaa || blaa)
   {
      //you have something to check here which testcases have exception or which testcase is executed
     run  your rest of test cases.
   testcase7
   .
   .
   testcase10
}
```

This code might be helpful to you. this is only logic, implementation you need to do..